# Why don't I get the Correct Result out of my Django Paginator

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, pagination

I am trying to create paginated pages in this view

```py
def all_users(request):
    users = Person.objects.all()
    pag = Paginator(users, 3)
    page_num = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = pag.get_page(page_num)

    context = {
        'users': users,
        'title': 'All Users',
        'page_obj': page_obj
    }
    return render(request, 'index/users.html', context)
```

Here is users.html :

```html
{%extends 'index/base.html'%}
{%block content%}
<section class="all-users">
    {%for user in users%}
    <article>
        <h1 class="username">{{user.username}}</h1>
        <hr>
        <p><b>Email: </b><span class="email" class="">{{user.email}}</span></p>
        <p><b>FirstName: </b><span class="first-name" class="">{{user.first_name}}</span></p>
        <p><b>LastName: </b><span class="last-name" class="">{{user.last_name}}</span></p>
        <p><b>Joined on: </b>{{user.date_joined}}</p>
        {%if is_staff%}
        <p>{{user.username} is a staff member</p>
        {%else%}
        <p><span class="full-name">{{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}</span>, a.k.a {{user.username}} is a normal member</p>
        {%endif%}
    </article>
    {%endfor%}
</section>

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    let users = '{{users}}' 

   
    for(let username of document.getElementsByClassName('username')){
        if (username.textContent.length >= 15 && username.textContent.length <= 20 ){
            username.style.fontSize = '30px'
        }else if (username.textContent.length >= 11 && username.textContent.length <= 14 ){
            username.style.fontSize = '45px'
        }
        }
</script>
{%endblock content%}
```

as you can see in the paginator i want three users per page
but that doesn't even work
I still see all the users(article boxes with the users info) all on one page!
There are no Error message anywhere

Comment: You should iterate over the objects in the paginator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over the objects in the `Page` object, as is for example described in the [*Paginating a `ListView`* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/pagination/#paginating-a-listview), so:

```
{% extends 'index/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<section class="all-users">
    {% for user in page_obj %}
        <!-- … -->
    {% endfor %}
</section>
```

So you iterate with `{% for user in page_obj %}` instead of `{% for user in users %}`.

`QuerySet`s are more or less mutable (well you can modify these yourself if you really want to, but that is not the intended way to use these). So the `Page` object will *not* modify the `QuerySet`, it will simply analyze it and make a new one internally and expose that one through the iterator protocol.